# On the Limit of Stirling's Approximation

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, asymptotics, factorial

I have recently proven the following curious identity: For real $x \geqslant 1$,
\begin{align}
\lfloor x \rfloor! = x^{\lfloor x \rfloor} e^{1-x} e^{\int_{1}^{x} \text{frac}(t)/t \ dt}
\end{align}
where $\text{frac}(x)$ denotes the fractional part (function) of $x$. A proof follows from an application of [Legendre's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Number_theory) on the order of a prime divisor of the factorial function and an identity involving the [de Bruijn function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number).

An asymptotic expansion of the integral as $x \to \infty$ yields [Stirling's Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), hence the title of the post. Is this exact result known in the literature?

Thanks!

Comment: +1: Very nice! Is the proof too involved to post here?

Comment: The proof of a much more general identity is a bit involved and too long to post here. The identity above is a special case.

Comment: @Aryabhata: See my recent post below.

Comment: Thank you for notifying me. I already did (and voted) :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although my question above concerns whether or not the posted identity is a known result, I'll add the following elementary and direct proof (without recourse to Legendre's Theorem or the de Bruijn function needed for a more general version).

**Proposition** For real $x \geqslant 1$, the following identity holds
\begin{align}
\lfloor x \rfloor! = x^{\lfloor x \rfloor} e^{1-x} e^{\int_1^{x} \frac{\text{frac}(t)}{t} \ dt}.
\end{align}

**Proof.** 
For each positive integer $n$, the function $f(t) = \tfrac{\text{frac}(t)}{t}$ equals $1 - \tfrac{n}{t}$ on $[n,n+1]$. Thus,
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{n} f(t) \ d t &  = \sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} \int_{k}^{k+1} (1 - \tfrac{k}{t}) \ dt \\ & = n - 1 + \log n! - n \log n.
\end{align}
By splitting the following integral into two pieces, we compute
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{x} f(t) \ d t & =\int_{1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} f(t)  \ d t + \int_{\lfloor x \rfloor }^{x} f(t)  \ dt \\ & =  \lfloor x \rfloor - 1 + \log \lfloor x \rfloor! - \lfloor x \rfloor \log \lfloor x \rfloor + \int_{\lfloor x \rfloor}^{x } f(t) \ d t.
\end{align}
We need only to compute the last integral,
\begin{align}
 \int_{\lfloor x \rfloor}^{x } f(t)  \ dt & =  \int_{0}^{\text{frac}(x)  } \frac{\text{frac}(t + \lfloor x \rfloor)}{t + \lfloor x \rfloor} \ d t \\ & =  \int_{0}^{ \text{frac}(x)  } \frac{t}{t + \lfloor x \rfloor } \ d t
  \\ & =\text{frac}(x)  + \lfloor x \rfloor \log \lfloor x \rfloor - \lfloor x \rfloor \log x
\end{align}
by a change of variables from $t$ to $t + \lfloor x \rfloor$. Hence, together these identities yield
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{x} f(t)  \ dt &  =   x   - 1 + \log \lfloor x \rfloor!      - \lfloor x \rfloor \log x,
\end{align}
which completes the proof of the claim.

Comment: @draks: Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 6):

That works. There are two parts. Write $x = n + \delta,$ with $n \in \mathbb Z$ and $0 \leq \delta < 1.$
Your identity
$$ \lfloor x \rfloor! = x^{\lfloor x \rfloor} e^{1-x} e^{\int_{1}^{x} \text{frac}(t)/t \ dt}.$$
becomes
$$  n! = (n + \delta)^n \; e^{1-n} \; e^{-\delta} \;  e^{\int_{1}^{n} \text{frac}(t)/t \ dt} \;  e^{\int_{n}^{n + \delta} \text{frac}(t)/t \ dt}  $$ 
As the left hand side $n!$ is independent of $\delta,$ we need the factor that depends on $\delta$ to be a constant (but depending on $n$). Note that
$$  {\int_{n}^{n + \delta} \text{frac}(t)/t \ dt} = \delta + n \log \left( \frac{n}{n+\delta} \right)  $$
So the factor
$$   (n + \delta)^n \;  e^{-\delta}  \;  e^{\int_{n}^{n + \delta} \text{frac}(t)/t \ dt} =  (n + \delta)^n \;  e^{-\delta}  \;  e^{\delta}   \; \left( \frac{n}{n+\delta} \right)^n = n^n $$
is indeed independent of $\delta,$ and your identity is
$$  n! = n^n \; e^{1-n} \;  e^{\int_{1}^{n} \text{frac}(t)/t \ dt}  .$$
This is rather cute. Proof by induction: it is true for $n=1,$ both sides are just $1.$ In the induction step, we get the right hand side with $(n+1)$ as
$$ RHS_{n+1} = (n+1)^{n+1} \; e^{-n} \;   e^{\int_{1}^{n} \text{frac}(t)/t \ dt} \;   e^{\int_{n}^{n+1} \text{frac}(t)/t \ dt}.   $$
The final factor is what we got with $\delta = 1,$ that is
$$  {\int_{n}^{n+1} \text{frac}(t)/t \ dt} = 1 + n \log \left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right)  $$
So
$$  RHS_{n+1} = (n+1) \; (n+1)^n \; e^{-n} \;  e^{\int_{1}^{n} \text{frac}(t)/t \ dt} \; \cdot e \cdot \; \left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right)^n   $$  and
$$  RHS_{n+1} = (n+1) \; n^n \; e^{1-n} \;  e^{\int_{1}^{n} \text{frac}(t)/t \ dt}  $$ and the induction hypothesis says 
$$  RHS_{n+1} = (n+1) \; n!  $$

Comment: Hi Will. Thanks for your observation. Once one has the identity, it can be proved by induction, as you've just demonstrated. My question is whether the identity has appeared in the literature.

Comment: @user02138, I really don't now.

Comment: +1.  I'm not terribly interested in whether or not this is a previously published result, I just wanted to see the proof, and this one is so nice!

Comment: @MattCalhoun, thank you.